# Download part of bytes FtpWebRequest c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm in the situation where I need live logs, but they cannot be added to a database table. I need them live, so I figure instead of downloading the entire log file every 25 seconds, I should download part of the bytes. I don't see any parameters in the FtpWebRequest where I can specify this.

So the question is: How do I download part of a file via FtpWebRequest? (eg. the first 1024 bytes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand you right then You can just Keep Downloading Till The Download hit the Size of bytes you want then you can stop your download and save the actual bytes

**EDIT :**

create the byte[] you want for example :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
```

you can download via FtpwebRequest using :

```
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
```

then keep writing the bytes in the buffer

```
 private void DownloadFile(string userName, string password, string ftpSourceFilePath, string localDestinationFilePath)
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

        FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpSourceFilePath, userName, password, true);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

        Stream reader = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localDestinationFilePath, FileMode.Create);

        while (true)
        {
            bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            if (bytesRead == 0)
                break;

            fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();       
    }
```

Comment: Correct. How do I do this? Got an example?